# Spring injection of Provider<String> is slow

Tags: spring

When injecting Provider, in the presence of many of these Providers, Spring acts very slow even though all requesting sites have @Named annotations on them.

This is especially worse when the Providers are chained (one provider calling another).

Answer (score 0):

This is due to lack of caching of the relation between the provider name and the provider class.

See https://github.com/bironran/spring_issues_generic_provider for discussion and workaround